# Merge the [barebones] tag into [bare-metal] and burninate unrelated taggings

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[bare-metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bare-metal) has a tag explanation and corresponds to the common usage of the term: doing assembly without an OS.

[barebones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/barebones) has only 12 questions, and is another term for "bare metal`" but it seems to be less used.

`barebones` does not have a description, and has been used as well on unrelated questions as well as an ill-defined concept, although the most common use case is `bare-metal`.

Can I merge `barebone` questions into `bare-metal` where it is correct, and burninate the rest?

EDIT: I've converted existing questions where `bare-metal` applies to it. I've left `barebones` in case someone some day finds a use for it, it will be easier to find existing questions.

Comment: Well the term barebones in general means something that has only the minimum requirements and not much more.  Barebones is probably a terrible tag, but I don't think your proposed synonym is quite accurate.

Comment: @ryanyuyu only a partial synonym, the rest burnination. Would require manual action on each tag.

Comment: Seems fine then.

Comment: Your question asks for a synonym, but you actually only want to kill the tag and salvage what questions you can? Go ahead, but consider bringing your question here in line with what you actually want to do!

Comment: @Deduplicator sorry, I'm not very familiar with tag synonyms, so it didn't cross my mind that the question title would be interpreted like that. I will proceed with the operation then.